# Endianness on Android when using AudioRecord with 16-bit PCM and reading into a byte array

Tags: android, audio-recording

I am currently examining an Android application that uses [AudioRecord](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html) to record audio in 16-bit PCM format:

```
byte [] buffer = new byte[1600];
audioRecord.read(buffer, 0, 1600);
```

It stores the recorded audio into `buffer`.The [documentation of this read function](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html#read(short%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20int)) describes that this function *should* only be used with 8-bit PCM. However, the Android application uses it with 16-bit PCM (and it seems to work without issues; another [overloaded read variant](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html#read(byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20int)) using a byte array also mentions that the use of 16-bit PCM with this method is *possible*, but deprecated).

Now I am unsure if each sample (consisting of 2 bytes) is stored in little or in big endian format. The [documentation section about the audio encoding](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioFormat#encoding) says that using a ByteBuffer instead of byte array results in native endian (instead of big endian).

I suspect that a short is stored in big endian format but I can not find evidence for this.

Answer (score 4):

I have the same situation in my recent project.

Method

```
public int read (byte[] audioData, 
            int offsetInBytes, 
            int sizeInBytes)
```

actually calls

```
public int read (byte[] audioData, 
            int offsetInBytes, 
            int sizeInBytes, 
            int readMode)
```

with AudioRecord.READ_BLOCKING as the 4th parameter. Since 16-bit PCM is deprecated, I think it's still ok to use this method just not recommended.

The read method finally calls native method native_read_in_byte_array to fill the audio buffer. Android is natively little-endian so native_read_in_byte_array stores audio data in little endian in C/C++ layer and then send audio data back to Java layer through JNI.

I did a quick test to find that byte buffer passing through JNI won't change the order in which it stores its bytes.

[image: native code]

[image: java code]

[image: screen print]

[image: native log print]

Basically you get your Java byte[] in the same order as in the C/C++ jbyteArray. So a short in native is still stored in little endian in Java layer.

That's all I can reason from my test. Hope it helps and let me know if something is wrong in there.

Comment: btw check cs.android.com for the native method native_read_in_byte_array

Answer (score 0):

It's Big Endian.

Here's the needle in the haystack - [https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioFormat#encoding:~:text=when%20the%20short%20is%20stored%20in%20a%20ByteBuffer%2C%20it%20is%20native%20endian%20(as%20compared%20to%20the%20default%20Java%20big%20endian)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioFormat#encoding:%7E:text=when%20the%20short%20is%20stored%20in%20a%20ByteBuffer%2C%20it%20is%20native%20endian%20(as%20compared%20to%20the%20default%20Java%20big%20endian))

It seems like Java stores everything in Big Endian.

Edit: This is only the case for byte[], according to the documentation you can supposedly use ByteBuffer which will store data in little endian.